# Can I UPSERT on Id using DBAmp?

Tags: upsert, etl, dbamp

I know I can upsert on an external Id in DBAmp. The DBAmp documentation makes a lot of reference to specifying the external Id in an upsert call, but no reference to making an upsert based on the standard Salesforce record Id field.

Has anybody done this? I can't think of a reason why it wouldn't be possible, but I don't see any reference to it on the internet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, I can UPSERT using the standard Salesforce ID field using DBAmp.

I've had someone in our organisation try it out, and it works just fine.

Comment: I've done it dozens of times.  It's just a text field when DBamp connects to the table.  Never had an issue.